# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Concept_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, configuration, system.xml

I try this with [Inchoo Tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/).
This was a common error, I tried to create a configuration to my extension.
this is very basic configuration creation with following files.

my **Config.xml** file : Path(\app\code\local\Wired\Concept\etc)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Concept>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wired_Concept>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <concept>
            <class>Wired_Concept_Model</class>
        </concept>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <concept>
            <class>Wired_concept_Helper</class>
        </concept>
    </helpers>
 </global>
<adminhtml>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <wired>
                                    <title>Wired - All</title>
                                </wired>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

My **system.xml** : Path(\app\code\local\Wired\Concept\etc)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <wired translate="label" module="concept">
        <label>Wired Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </wired>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <wired translate="label" module="concept">
        <label>Extension Options</label>
        <tab>wired</tab>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </wired>
<groups>
<wired_group translate="label" module="concept">
                <label>My Extension Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <fields>
                    <wired_input translate="label">
                        <label>My Input Field: </label>
                        <comment>My Comment</comment>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </wired_input>
                    <wired_select translate="label">
                        <label>My Dropdown: </label>
                        <comment>Source model provider Magento's default Yes/No values</comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    </wired_select>
                </fields>
            </wired_group>
        </groups>
</sections>
</config>
```

My **Data.php Helper** File : Path(app\code\local\Wired\Concept\Helper)

```
<?php
class Wired_Concept_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

My **Wired_Concept.xml** file : Path(app\etc\modules)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Concept>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Wired_Concept>
</modules>
</config>
```

I tried several ways and read several pages.But i can't figure out my problem, Definitely i can understand my helper file is missing some thing, with my eye i can't see that.
Pls Help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the Helper class wrongly in config.xml.

Check below for  your code snippet

```
<helpers>
        <concept>
            <class>Wired_concept_Helper</class>
        </concept>
    </helpers>
```

Here the class should be

```
<class>Wired_Concept_Helper</class>
```

Comment: Thank you.with this edit i can show the configuration bar.But i cant view the extensions options any idea?

Comment: I am not clear by extensions options.. what do you mean by that?

Comment: please have a look at my question edit on system.xml file.

Comment: i am not clear what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: My purpose of the question was achieved with your answer.i tried with this article http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/.As it is apper in the article i can't get the view.If you can please check the image under this line "And if you’ve done everything correctly you should see something like this:" in that inchoo website tutorial.it will be great help.if you cnt view this link pls use the questions link.

Comment: are you trying to say you are not able to retrieve the value of config or not able to see the config section?

Comment: not able to see the config section.only the menu part is appearing click event is not working.

Comment: its turning out to be confusing could you please ask a new question with screenshot on whats happening

Comment: Thanks Dexter,its working fine now.May be some cache issues.

Comment: You should always take care of caches

Answer (score 2):

1.You missed out the closing tag `</config>` in `app\etc\modules\Wired_Concept.xml`. So that it not appear in admin configuration section and cause error.

2.You have to close `</wired>` tag after `</groups>` tag in `\app\code\local\Wired\Concept\etc\system.xml`.

Please refer and replace the code below in `system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <wired translate="label" module="concept">
        <label>Wired Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </wired>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <wired translate="label" module="concept">
        <label>Extension Options</label>
        <tab>wired</tab>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

        <groups>
            <wired_group translate="label" module="concept">
                <label>My Extension Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <fields>
                    <wired_input translate="label">
                        <label>My Input Field: </label>
                        <comment>My Comment</comment>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </wired_input>
                    <wired_select translate="label">
                        <label>My Dropdown: </label>
                        <comment>Source model provider Magento's default Yes/No values</comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    </wired_select>
                </fields>
            </wired_group>
        </groups>
    </wired>
</sections>
</config>
```

Now check in your admin section

Comment: it was a by mistake, but the config tag is closed in the local file.Thank you.

Comment: ok. You checked system.xml ?

Comment: Yes venkat. The issue was corrected with the first answer.Thank you.

Comment: sounds good :).